Movie with Heracles/Hercules character
I do not remember too much about the plot of the movie just remember one scene. I watched this some time in late 80s.
Hercules and his friend are captured. They are made to find blind folded with daggers or shorts while trying to balance themselves on the beam that is above some sort of spikes. They start to fight but during the fight they realize that they know each other, they take off the blindfolds.
I remember Hercules character being strong but not anything spectacular.
At this time I can't even remember if it was black and white or in color. Movie had a vibe of movies like Cleopatra or Spartacus and other movies about Roman or Greek empires with all men walking in tunics and main heroes being very well built.

Your description is lacking one important thing: Do you know from which time this has been? At first I thought about Hercules - The Legendary Journey with Kevin Sorbo as Hercules, but at the same time you could be talking about one of the many classic US/German/Italian co-productions as well.

Definitely not from a series with Kevin Sorbo, recently watched most of it and it looks nothing similar. That movie had that classic feel to it. If I had to guess movie was made in 60s or before.

Okay, so most likely from 60/70's with possibly US/IT/DE actors like Spartacus?

Actors from Hercules, Samson & Ulysses looks very familiar, but than again it could have been just one of many movies that watched at the same time

Could it be Hercules Against Rome (1964)

Hercules comes from Greece to Ravenna, Italy, because a friend from
  childhood days has sent for him: Hercules should help the Roman
  Emperor who is in danger because of an intrigue lead by the leader of
  the pretorian guards.

Or possibly Hercules, Prisoner of Evil

looks like I will need it to watch it again to know for sure, never really realized how many movies of similar genre came from that time. I watched a clip from that Hercules Against Rome and it looked promising.
